# What is the usage of sorted command?

Tags: linux, unix

I have read most of the example comes with sort command. How ever I am not sure what is the usage of sort command in this style?

```
sort <word> sorted
```

Answer (score 2):

That would just be two file names, as in

```
sort file1 file2 file3...
```

If you pass multiple file names, `sort` concatenates them and sorts all of them together.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to sort a string with the sort command:

```
echo "tatoine" | grep -o . | sort | tr -d "\n"
aeinott
```

because sort operate on lines so you've got to cut the string in multiple lines with one letter on each (grep -o .) and after sorting you just delete the new lines with the tr command.

Answer (score 0):

Are those < and > symbols explicit, or do they indicate a  parameter that is to be replaced?  If the latter, then you're reading from a file called "word", and writing the sorted data to a file called "sorted".

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save the content in a sorted order?

Let's say you have a file name.txt with the following content.

```
Zoe
John
Amy
Mary
Mark
Peter
```

You can use the sort commmand "sort name.txt" and the output goes to the console
You can save the output using "sort name.txt -o sortedname.txt"

e.g.

```
Amy
John
Mark
mary
Peter
Zoe
```

You can found more option with the command "man sort" and "info sort"

rojomoke was right about the > and < commands.  Those are redirection commands. 
We usually read the data from standard input (stdin) and output goes to standard output aka the screen (stdout)

`<` means get the data from somewhere else. e.g. a file.

`>` means redirect the output to somewhere else e.g. a file.

So for the command above `"sort name.txt -o sortedname.txt"`, I could have written as follow.

```
sort < name.txt > sortedname.txt
```

You can read more about the redirection in this wiki entry.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)

Commands like `| >>` will come in handy down the road.